# Console.WriteLine no existe en el contexto actual

Tags: c#

primero que nada siento que voy a preguntar una obviedad, pero estuve buscando a que se puede deber el error que voy a dejar abajo, pero no pude dar con una solución.
Lo que pasa es lo siguiente, tengo varias clases creadas en mi programa, todas andan de 10, salvo esta que acabo de crear, quiero usar funciones básicas de IO como el Console.WriteLine(); pero me tira un error similar a cuando te olvidas del "using System;", de echo, el "using System;" sale en gris como si nada lo estaría usando. Adjunto código.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace main
{
    class Menu
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hola");
    }
}
```

Y ya que estoy, quiero aprovechar a preguntar, cual es la diferencia entre los signos que preceden el nombre de las clases, me refiero al tilde rojo y a la cruz verde, el tilde rojo dice pendiente de edición y la cruz pendiente de agregación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás usando Git, un control de versiones: el check rojo indica cambios en ese archivo, el signo + verde indica que has agregado ese archivo.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora solo me queda por solucionar el error con el Console.WriteLine();

Comment: Ese `Console.WriteLine` Debería estar en el Program.cs porque si lo quieres dentro de la clase Menu, debería estar dentro de algún método. Toma, te será de ayuda: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/csharpya/